# java throws impossible NullPointerException

Tags: java, generics, jdbc, nullpointerexception

Reduced to the essentials I have the following code:

```
public class C_Test extends A_Test {
    C_Test() {
        super( null );
    }
}

public abstract class A_Test {
    private final String m_test;

    public A_Test( String test ) {
        m_test = C_ObjectUtil.defaultIfNull( test, "" );

        if( m_test == null ) {
            throw new RuntimeException( "it happened again!" );
        }
    }
}

public class C_ObjectUtil {
    public static <T> T defaultIfNull( T object, T defaultObject ) {
        return ( object == null ) ? defaultObject : object;
    }
}
```

After reading about 70 MB of data from a DB2 database using JDBC a call of `new C_Test()` throws the impossible Exception. Up to that time the constructor was called more than 100000 times.

After inlining the method `defaultIfNull` into the constructor `A_Test` (this removes the generics) everything works without any error!

Environment: Sun JDK 1.7.0_25 64Bit, Linux

**Any idea what's happenig here?**

---

Here comes the stacktrace. It does not match to the reduced version I've shown above. The exception here is thrown when calling `m_test.equals( "null" )` in the constructor `A_Test`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.src.db.attribvisitors.A_AttribVisitorAssignFromResultSet.<init>(A_AttribVisitorAssignFromResultSet.java:54)
        at com.src.db.attribvisitors.C_AttribVisitorAssignFromSelectStatement.<init>(C_AttribVisitorAssignFromSelectStatement.java:37)
        at com.src.db.attribvisitors.C_AttribVisitorAssignFromSelectStatement.<init>(C_AttribVisitorAssignFromSelectStatement.java:43)
        at com.src.framework.db.migration.A_DbTableRow.initFromResultset(A_DbTableRow.java:96)
        at com.src.framework.db.migration.helper.C_DbTableProcessor$1.process(C_DbTableProcessor.java:66)
        at com.src.db.C_TxSql.query(C_TxSql.java:144)
        at com.src.db.C_SqlExecuter$3.execute(C_SqlExecuter.java:142)
        at com.src.db.C_SqlExecuter.execute(C_SqlExecuter.java:80)
        at com.src.db.C_SqlExecuter.query(C_SqlExecuter.java:138)
        at com.src.framework.db.migration.helper.C_DbTableProcessor.processTable(C_DbTableProcessor.java:58)
        at com.src.framework.db.migration.helper.C_DbTableProcessor.processTable(C_DbTableProcessor.java:39)
        at com.src.tools.C_DbExporter.exportTable(C_DbExporter.java:93)
        at com.src.tools.C_DbExporter.exportTables(C_DbExporter.java:77)
        at com.src.tools.C_DbExporter.exportTables(C_DbExporter.java:61)
        at com.src.tools.C_DbExporterAndImporter.exportTables(C_DbExporterAndImporter.java:95)
        at com.src.tools.C_DbExporterAndImporter.doMain(C_DbExporterAndImporter.java:83)
        at com.src.common.C_MainUtil.runMain(C_MainUtil.java:150)
        at com.src.tools.C_DbExporterAndImporter.main(C_DbExporterAndImporter.java:57)
```

Comment: The problem with these kinds of "impossible things" is that when you "reduce the code to essentials" you get rid of the actual bug. Of course this **could** be a bug in JIT, but let's not jump to conclusions. Can you try with a different JVM?

Comment: Before you post code that is "reduced to the essentials", you should test if the example you're posting works or not...

If it does, the bug is elsewhere and you should keep searching.

Comment: The real code is way to big to post it. But I have reduced it to the minimum environment that could be important.

Comment: @tangens Nobody can help you when you post working code, and say I have an error.

Comment: I'm looking for ideas how this could happen. As I said, I get a member with a `null` value on a line I think this is impossible.

Comment: @tangens Are there more than one thread in this application? Are you potentially leaking this from your constructor?

Comment: I tried your code, I can't replicate the NPE in this scenario, have you tried the same code using another java version?, i'm using jdk1.6

Comment: @Cruncher No, it's a single threaded application.

Comment: @tangens my suggestion, is the take this "bare essential" example, and start building back up to what you currently have. Somewhere between here and there, a bug will be introduced. If at that time you don't understand the bug, then you can come post

Comment: I have only one environment that produces this error. It's a customer environment where I'm not able to install a different JVM.

Comment: @tangens alternatively, step through your program in debug mode and look at the memory as you go.

Comment: @Cruncher Would be great, but it's not possible. There is no graphical environment installed on the machine and I only have a remote desktop to administer. And no way to forward ports for remote debugging.

Comment: The can go away by inlining code, so there is no immediate action neccessary. But I'm very confused by this bug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched from **Sun JDK 1.7.0_25 64Bit** to **Sun JDK 1.7.0_55 64Bit** and the NPE disappeared!

Answer (score 3):

Without any outside intervention which you aren't showing us, this isn't possible.

This invocation

```
m_test = C_ObjectUtil.defaultIfNull( test, "" );
```

pushes the value that `test` holds and the value of the reference to the `String` literal `""` on the stack. The method is invoked, consuming those two references. Then this is invoked

```
public static <T> T defaultIfNull( T object, T defaultObject ) {
    return ( object == null ) ? defaultObject : object;
}
```

the value from `test`, ie. `null`, is bound to `object` and the value of the reference to the `String` is bound to `defaultObject`. The conditional operator is executed and `defaultObject` is returned, ie. the non-null `String`. That is assigned to `m_test` in the calling code. Nothing can intercept these steps in your code. Not another thread, not any proxying mechanism (it's a `static` method invoked directly), not anything I can think of.

Your error is elsewhere.

(I'll delete or edit this answer if you post new details that will help identify the true issue.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I really have no idea where to look for the bug. It goes away if I inline the method `defaultIfNull` and it comes back again if I don't.

Comment: @tangens Other than telling you it's impossible (failing a bug, but I doubt that), I can't guess what is going on. IMO, you'll have to find a way to reproduce it and show us.

Comment: @tangens Does C_ObjectUtil have a name that some other class has an you're importing the wrong one? (stab in the dark)

Comment: @Cruncher Good idea, but I have not found any collisions :-(

Comment: @tangens have you tried giving the method concrete parameter and return types?

Comment: @tangens And don't forget to log the value of each parameter and variable.

Comment: Right now I'm trying to reproduce the bug with a local system. I've already mirrored the database, but on my local windows system everything works fine. Next I'm going to try it inside a linux vm.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is very unlikely. However, it would not be the first time for the very unlikely to occur. I'm somewhat hesitant to post this as an answer because it really isn't one, but here we go.

As Kayaman [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300276/java-throws-impossible-nullpointerexception#comment35669189_23300276), the described behavior might be due to an incorrect JIT optimization. To test this theory, I would perform two steps.

1. Turn on `-XX:+PrintCompilation` and monitor the output for compilation of relevant methods right before the ominous exception occurs. **This by itself is no proof** that the JIT compiler is applying an incorrect optimization. However, it's enough to commence step two and see what machine code the JIT is producing.
2. Turn on [`-XX:+PrintAssembly`](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PrintAssembly) and go through the machine code the compiler output for the relevant method(s). This is a lot of work, especially when you are doing it for the first time.

The way I see it, there are three possibilities.

- It's a (subtle) bug in your code — nothing to do with the JIT.
- The JIT is actually wrong (unlikely, sorry). You should by able to prove it in step (2) above.
- The JIT is right, but it's (valid) optimization triggers an otherwise dormant bug. There's a decent chance you'll find it during step (2) above.

One last thing to point out — already [alluded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300276/java-throws-impossible-nullpointerexception#comment35669408_23300276) to by Cruncher — is the possibility of a race condition. Race conditions deserve a special mention because they they fall somewhere in between the first and third category. They may have nothing to do with an optimization per se, but the optimization's speed up may enable an unwanted and otherwise unachievable execution trace.

I wish you best of luck on your hunt. :)

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. That's very heavy stuff! I don't know if I can afford the time to dig through this. But I think this would be the right way to narrow down the bug.